# Add an if statement inside a for loop condition

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a for loop to minimize this code, any ideas?

```
hello=5
if [[ -n hello ]]; then 
    for ((n=0; n<hello; n++));
    do
        echo "Running: `ps $user | wc -l` instance(s) ...";
    done
else
    while :
    do
        echo "Running: `ps $user  | wc -l` instance(s) ...";
    done
fi
```

I've tried something like that

```
for ((n=0;n<hello; [[ -n $hello ]] && n++ || n));
```

But it does not seem to work.

The idea is quite simple, if $hello exist run the number of iterations it states, otherwise run it infinite amount of times.

Comment: "_But it does not seem to work_". What happens, or what doesn't happen? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I would suggest that for diagnostic purposes, you put a sleep inside the loop, and number the output lines serially. To make it one loop, check `man bash` for how to default a variable to a given value if it is not set. Bash uses 32-bit integers, and a default of 2147483647 is as near infinity as you need.

Comment: Are you sure you don't actually want to use `watch` here?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, it uses 64-bit ints for arithmetic! AFAIK on 32-bit systems too. So you can use `$(( 2**63 - 1 ))` for "near infinity". (the mksh I have seems to use 32-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from just using a "big enough" number like 2147483647 (2<sup>31</sup> - 1) or 999999999999999 for "no limit", it's relatively common to let a value like -1 or 0 mean that.

I might go with something like this for -1 being the "no limit":

```
#!/bin/bash
count=5
[ -n "$1" ] && count=$1
for ((i=0; count == -1 || i < count; i++)); do
    echo "doing something for the ${i}th time"
    sleep .1
done
```

Or you could have a separate variable to tell if the limit exists or not:

```
has_limit=0
for ((i=0; ! has_limit || i < count; i++)); do
    ...
```

But of course then the user needs to input two values, one of which makes the other meaningless.

---

As for this:

```
for ((n=0;n<hello; [[ -n $hello ]] && n++ || n));
```

The insides of `for (( ... ))` are arithmetic contexts, so you can't run arbitrary shell code in there. You could do it similarly to the way I did above, but at least I find it cleaner to put that sort of test in the middle condition part of the `for (( ))`. That way you get to keep the increasing loop counter too, in case you need to count the iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
count=0

while true; do
    [ -n "$n" ] && [ "$count" -ge "$n" ] && break

    echo 'some string'
    sleep 1

    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

This combines your two loops into a single `while` loop that runs until `break` is executed.  This happens when the variable `n` is not empty and numerically less than or equal to the value of the variable `count`.

If `n` is unset or empty, the loop runs until terminated by external means.

The code could be shortened into

```bsh
count=0

until [ -n "$n" ] && [ "$count" -ge "$n" ]; do
    echo 'some string'
    sleep 1

    count=$(( count + 1 ))
done
```

Both of these loops should be usable in any POSIX-like shell.